# Upgrade to Zoo 3.2 without update custom apps

Tags: joomla, upgrade, zoo, joomla3.2, yoothemes

If we update zoo to version 3.2 without changing our custom apps as stated in http://yootheme.com/zoo/documentation/developers/make-apps-ready-for-zoo32, all work properly? (We do not edit from the frontend, we manage everything from backend)

Thanks!

Comment: If you've followed the steps mentioned by Yootheme then the upgrade will be fine. If you're really unsure, take a backup of your site, install on your local host or create a sub-domain and test there.

Comment: This question is about Joomla extensions, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Tested!

If you do not use ACL or frontend edition, you can upgrade Zoo to version 3.2 and everything still works properly.

Thanks for your feedback and support by Malte (http://yootheme.com/support/question/71961)